# A proof about equivalence relation and classes

Tags: relations, solution-verification

> Let $R$ be an equivalence relation in the set $A$ and $a,b \in A$. Show that $R(a)=R(b)$ **iff** $aRb$.

We must prove two implications here. First, that $$R(a)=R(b) \Rightarrow aRb$$

Note that $R(a):= \{b\in A : aRb\}$, and $R(b):=\{a\in A : bRa\}$. Also since these sets are equal, they must be subsets of each other $$R(a) \subseteq R(b)$$

It follows that $\forall b \in A$ : $$b\in R(a) \Rightarrow b \in R(b)$$

If $b$ is an element of both of these equivalence classes, then certainly $b=a$. From the fact that $$R(b)\subseteq R(a)$$

it follows similarly, that $a=b$. I'm pretty sure this shows
 $aRb$, but I'm not sure how I should word it. As for $$aRb \Rightarrow R(a)=R(b)$$

Since $R$ is an equivalence relation, we have by symmetry that, $\forall a,\forall b \in A$ $$aRb \Rightarrow bRa$$

This is where I am at the moment. I just wanted to check if the proof is ok up to this point.

Comment: "If b is an element of both of these equivalency classes, then certainly b=a"  Um.... is the equal sign supposed to mean ... equal?????   That is a  very strange and weird claim.  Consider $[2]_5 =\{n\in \mathbb Z:  5|(n-2)\}$ and $[7]_5=\{n\in\mathbb Z: 5|(n-7)\}$.  Then $5|7-2=5$ so $7\in [2]_5$ and $5|7-7=0$ so $7\in [7]_5$ but it is certainly *NOT* the case that $7 = 2$!

Comment: "Since R is an equivalence relation, we have by symmetry that, ∀a,∀b∈A"  This is obviously not true.  Consider the equivalence relation $aRb \iff 5|(a-b)$.  then let $a=31$ and $b= 24$.  Then $5\not \mid (31-24)=7$ and $31\not R 24$!  I think you have having trouble in reuising the same two variables $a,b$ in different context.  In the problem they are *specific* values. But in the definitions they are *general*.

Comment: Define $R(a) := \{x \in A| xRa\}$ and $R(b) = \{y\in A|yRb\}$ to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If b is an element of both of these equivalency classes, then certainly b=a

I can not see how you think that.  That makes no sense.  Unless this class has only one element, then (because they are equal) *all* the elements are in both and all the elements can't all be equal to each other.

.....

Use the definition of equivalence.

So to prove $R(a)=R(b)\to aRb$.....

If $R(a) = \{x\in A: aRx\}$....(I advice not using the variable "$b$" because you use that variable for another element... oh, maybe that caused your confusion....)

then as $R$ is an equivalence class then by reflexivity $aRa$ and so $a \in R(a)$.

But if $R(a) = R(b) = \{x\in A: bRx\}$ it follows that $a\in R(b)$ so $bRa$.

......

Can you finish this?

> but symmetry as $bRa$ we know $aRb$.

And to prove $aRb \to R(a)=R(b)$.

> If $c\in R(a)$ then $cRa$ but $aRb$ so .......

.........

> .... by transitivity $cRb$ so ...

.......

> ..... $c \in R(b)$ and $R(a)\subset R(b)$.  If $c \in R(b)$ then .....

......

> ...... $cRb$.  But $aRb$ so by symmetry $bRa$ and by transitivity $cRa$ and be symmettry $aRc$ so $c\in R(a)$ so $R(b)\subset R(a)$ and so $R(a) = R(b)$.

=========

It may help to do an example.  $\equiv \pmod 5$ is an equivalence relation.

So $[a] = \{x\in \mathbb Z| x\equiv a \pmod 5\}= \{a + 5k|k\in \mathbb N\}$ and $[b] = \{x\in \mathbb Z| x\equiv a \pmod 5\}= \{b + 5k|k\in \mathbb N\}$.

the does  $[a] = [b]$ mean that $b\equiv a \pmod 5$?

Well, yes....

$a \equiv a \pmod 5$ so $a \in [a] = [b]$ so $a\equiv b\pmod 5$ so $b \equiv a\pmod 5$.

If if $a \equiv b\pmod 5$ does that mean $[a] = [b]$?

Well, yes.....

If $a \equiv \pmod 5$ then there is a $k$ so that $a = b + 5k$.

Then $c\in [a]\iff c \equiv a \pmod 5\iff $ there is a $j$ so that $c = a+5j\iff c=(b+5k)+5j=b+5(k+j)\iff c\equiv b\pmod 5\iff c\in [b]$.

So $[a]$ and $[b]$ have the exact same elements.

====

In general.

Suppose $R(a) = R(b)$. then $bRb\implies b\in R(b)\implies b\in R(a)\implies aRb$.

Suppose $aRb$. then $c\in R(a)\implies aRc\implies cRa\implies cRa$ and $aRb\implies cRb \implies c\in R(b)\implies cRb\implies cRb$ and $ aRb\implies cRb$ and $bRa\implies cRa\implies c\in R(a)$.

So $c\in R(a)\iff c\in R(b)$ and so $R(a) = R(b)$.

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

If $aRb$, then $x \in R(a)$ implies that $xRa$ since $R$ is symmetric so by transivity $xRb$ and $x \in R(b)$. The other inclusion is similar. We know that $bRb$ by reflexivity so that if $R(a) = R(b)$, then $b \in R(a$) and $aRb$.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like that.

Suppose first that $R(a)=R(b)$.
As $R$ is reflexive, we have $aRa$ which implies $a\in R(a)$. By hypothesis, we also have $a \in R(b)$, i.e $aRb$.

Conversely let’s suppose that $aRb$ and take $c \in R(a)$, which means $cRa$. By transitivity, we also have  $cRb$, i.e. $c \in R(b)$. Therefore, we have proven that  $R(a)\subseteq R(b)$. Now, by symmetry if we suppose $aRb$, we also have $bRa$. With a similar proof that what we just did, we can conclude that $R(b) \subseteq R(a)$. Finally $R(a)=R(b)$.

*Overall, I would suggest that you use more explicitly the properties of an equivalence relation.*